# How do I create a permanent ACL in Centos using setfacl and Dockerfile

Tags: docker, acl, centos7

I am trying to set permission for one group to have access to a directory that contains constantly regenerated directories and files.

The directory '/var/lib/mod_tile' is owned by the group 'mappers' and the user 'gis'. The permissions on the folder are 755 (user: rwx, group: rx, other: rx)

The subdirectories in this folder are deleted and recreated at frequent intervals and I have no control over the permissions on those directories as they are generated by another piece of software. The permissions of the generated subdirectories are 755 (same as above).

I want to create an ACL to allow my group 'mappers' to have write access to these folders. I am running the follow commands in a Dockerfile:

```
RUN setfacl -Rm g:mappers:rwx /var/lib/mod_tile
RUN setfacl -Rdm g:mappers:rwx /var/lib/mod_tile
```

This gives my directory and its subdirectories rwx permissions to the group mappers. It makes all current and new subdirectories/files have those permissions.

However, after I build my image and run

```
docker run -it
```

and check the permissions with

```
setfacl /var/lib/mod_tile
```

the ACL's are gone and the program I am using cannot write to these folders when run by another user in the group 'mappers'.

I then manually run the same commands and when I run

```
setfacl /var/lib/mod_tile
```

The permissions are there! This leads me to believe that the ACL's are not persisted on each boot of the machine

Is there any way to persist the ACL's even on reboot?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59043049/setfacl-in-dockerfile-has-no-effect